# How do I run an external command on the current selection in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently switching editors from Vim to VS Code. One feature I like in vim is the ability to run an external command on a region of text (the `:!` command). I've been unable to find an obvious equivalent in VS Code.

Is this feature available in VS Code? Or is there an extension that provides it?

(As a more general question, what's the best way of finding out things like this? Is there a website or anything that describes how to do common tasks from other editors in VS Code?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having searched some more (the key term is "filter the selection") I found the [Filter Text](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yhirose.FilterText) extension, which does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 8):

For the record, VSCodeVim allows you to do the same thing.

[image]